# TypeScript How to paste data from clipboard using a button?

Tags: angular, typescript, clipboard

I am able to copy data to the clipboard using a button press as seen below. But how can use the same behavior to get data from the clipboard? The paste event only works when I click into an input field or text area. I need it to be able to work using a button.

I tried using window.clipboardData but it doesn't recognize it. Is there a way I can fire the Paste event through a button press?

```
 Copy(val) {
    const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
     selBox.style.position = 'fixed';
     selBox.style.left = '0';
     selBox.style.top = '0';
     selBox.style.opacity = '0';
     selBox.value = val;

     document.body.appendChild(selBox);
     selBox.focus();
     selBox.select();

     document.execCommand('copy');
     document.body.removeChild(selBox);
     this.icon = 'checkmark';
     this.copyButtonText = 'Copied!';
     this.tooltip = true;
 }
```

my html

```
   <button #copyButton [icon]='this.icon' (click)="Copy(this.text)">{{copyButtonText}}</button>    
   <textarea [disabled]="true"> {{this.text}} </textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to use window selection handler.

```
let clipboardContent:string = "" //the clipboard content variable

window.addEventListener('copy', (e:ClipboardEvent) => {
  clipboardContent = window.getSelection().toString();
  //everytime someone copies some thing its text content 
  //is available within the clipboardContent variable
});

//now for the button press event you have the clipboard data
buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //paste your content
  textareaElement.value = clipboardContent;
});
```

Comment: This works great for things being copied inside the web app. What if they copy things from outside the app? Like Sql Server or Excel. How can I capture that event? Is that even possible?

Comment: No, you cannot capture events outside the browser.