# What is the equivalent code for navigator.clipboard.readText() in angular

Tags: angular, clipboarddata, clipboard-interaction

```
navigator.clipboard.readText()
  .then(text => {
    // `text` contains the text read from the clipboard
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // maybe user didn't grant access to read from clipboard
    console.log('Something went wrong', err);
  });
```

[above code is from](https://alligator.io/js/async-clipboard-api/)

I need to read from clipboard on button click in angular 
How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

By your question I see that you're missing something important. Your angular app is written in [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), which is:

> a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript

It means that the [clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) you've mentioned is available to you in angular! as you can see in this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clipboard-readtext) which is using your code.

Currently typescript has the `navigator` type as [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/phonegap--phonegap/interfaces/navigator.html), but unfortunately it still doesn't contains the clipboard API since it's still a *non-standard DOM APIs* as you can see in this git closed issue - *[Missing 'Navigator.clipboard' (clipboard asynchronous API)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26728)*

Answer (score 0):

from this [TypeScript How to paste data from clipboard using a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420868/typescript-how-to-paste-data-from-clipboard-using-a-button), using hostListener

```
  @HostListener("window:copy",['e'])
  windowCopy(e:ClipboardEvent){
      this.clipboardContent = window.getSelection().toString();
      console.log(this.clipboardContent)
  }
```

Comment: not working if you copy from other source that window